# What is the generalized binary coding difference between an array and an object?

Tags: arrays, object, binary

In C-family coding languages such as C, PHP, Perl and Java, what is the difference in how arrays and objects are coded in binary?

Is there a single primary data structure that is universal to all arrays and objects, and then one or more secondary data structures that are attached to the primary? As follows:

[image: Posited Array/Object sub-structure]

The alternative to that would be a unique primary data structure for arrays and objects. Probably, that would mean arrays have the data values located right in the primary indicators whereas objects would have a data index that lead to data repositories in the memory.

Comment: In C, an "object" is some space in memory that can hold a value.  It has a size, a type, and an address.  An array is one type of object.  Types, however, are compile-time concepts and have no space or object associated with them at runtime.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks, that answers my question. I've been thinking about writing languages and I have different ideas for the data flow - if arrays are effectively objects, it suggests that the data flow I illustrated above is being used because objects have variable sizes in the memory, meaning multiple concatenated data structures must be used.

Comment: Generally the size of an object is not stored anywhere in memory -- it is implicit from the type and, like the type, only exists an compile time.  At runtime you just have data (value) bits in the memory.  This is (part of) why in C all arrays are fixed size.